# Current Iteration Query Script Devops Looping Through Projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to put a script together that will let me loop through projects and create queries relevant to the current iteration.

I can loop through and create queries until it comes to looking at the iteration path and then it doesn't seem to like it.

When I run my script all of the other queries are created, and this one is as well, but it brings up an error when I go to look at it because it's posting that it's not in the right form.  How can I get this query to loop through like the others and bring back the appropriate team in the process?

[image]

I'm assuming that somehow I've got to put project and team as variables? I tried $project as well but that just presented a similar error.  Although I'm also confused about about the "" since the code doesn't like that either, and it won't even create the query when I've tried that.

```html
    $JSON27 = @'
    {
      "name": "Current Sprint Query", "wiql": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State],[System.Tags],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork],[System.IterationPath] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] <> '' AND [System.State] = 'Closed' AND [System.IterationPath] = @CurrentIteration('[Project]/Team')  ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType]"
      }
'@
```

```html
 $response27 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON27 -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: Please post the contents/screenshot of the error you see.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara - I've made a couple of edits to show the error in DevOps and explain a bit more on where my confusion is :)

Comment: Ahh, that helps, thanks. So, as the error message calls out, I think the issue is that you have `@CurrentIteration('[Project]/Team')` in your query instead of `@CurrentIteration('[Project]\Team')`. I'm almost sure this would solve your issue, but please check and confirm. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following script to get the project name first, and then create a query by looping through the obtained project name.

Please use **@CurrentIteration('[Project]\\Team')** instead of @CurrentIteration('[Project]/Team') or @CurrentIteration('[Project]\Team')

```
$token = "your PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/org name/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

echo $url 

foreach ($project in $response.value.name){
   
  $url3="https://dev.azure.com/org name/$($project)/_apis/wit/queries/My Queries?api-version=6.1-preview.2"

  echo $url1

  $body = "{
    `"name`": `"query name`",
    `"wiql`": `"Select [System.Id], [System.State] From WorkItems where [System.IterationPath] = @CurrentIteration('[$project]\\$project Team') `"
        }"

echo $body

$response3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url3 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json

echo $response3

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Summarizing the discussion in comments as an answer below:*

So, as the error message calls out, I think the issue is that you have `@CurrentIteration('[Project]/Team')` in your query instead of `@CurrentIteration('[Project]\Team')`.

Your query should be this instead:

```
$JSON27 = @'
    {
        "name": "Current Sprint Query", "wiql": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State],[System.Tags],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork],[System.IterationPath] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] <> '' AND [System.State] = 'Closed' AND [System.IterationPath] = @CurrentIteration('[Project]\Team')  ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType]"
    }
'@
```

**EDIT:**

By default, shared queries and new queries are scoped to the current project. For [querying across multiple projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#query-across-projects), you can add the `TeamProject` field to filter to a select number of projects as:

```
..
AND [System.TeamProject] IN ('Project 1', 'Project 2', 'Project 3')
```

However, using the **@CurrentIteration** macro would need you to select a Team and may not work across Projects and Teams. Check this [idea](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/440021/support-4.html) on Developer Community for more details.

Comment: Afraid that doesn't do the job either.  The query doesn't get created when changing to a "\"  so I think there's something else that I'm missing... as I'm looping through projects in my org (e.g. Project 1, Project 2, Project Dave, Project James, etc) is there something else I have to do. It's almost like it needs to be "/" to create the query but it needs "\" for the condition to work? Do I need $Project in there somewhere as well for example (I've tried a few different variations of that but again it doesn't create the query at all so I'm likely mistaken on that too)

Comment: @James Oh, sry for overlooking that part. Edited my answer to address that question.

Comment: Think I may have confused things.  I want to create the query in each and every project so that it can pick up the right project and team as part of the script. I've got a For Each which I'm using to create the queries, it's just that I can't find a way of putting the project and team together with the CurrentIteration macro.